# Answering bot title position & send button not working

Tags: javascript, position, chat, css-position

Before I ask my questions, let me show you the full code for the project I'm working on (I'm making a bot that answers questions given some key words. It's a very easy code developed by Deni Spasovski).

This is the main HTML file:

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chat.js"></script>


<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #edeff2;
  font-family: "Calibri", "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.chat_window {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top_menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.top_menu .buttons {
  margin: 3px 0 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
.top_menu .buttons .button {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.top_menu .buttons .button.close {
  background-color: #f5886e;
}
.top_menu .buttons .button.minimize {
  background-color: #fdbf68;
}
.top_menu .buttons .button.maximize {
  background-color: #a3d063;
}
.top_menu .title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #bcbdc0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.messages {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 10px 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 347px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.messages .message {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
.messages .message.right .text {
  color: #45829b;
}
.messages .message.appeared {
  opacity: 1;
}
.messages .message .avatar {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: calc(100% - 85px);
  min-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::after, .messages .message .text_wrapper:before {
  top: 18px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::after {
  border-width: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper::before {
  border-width: 15px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper .text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bottom_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;

}
.bottom_wrapper .message_input_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #bcbdc0;
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
   word-wrap: break-word;   
    word-break: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
.bottom_wrapper .message_input_wrapper .message_input {
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  position: absolute;
  outline-width: 0;
  outline:none;
  color: gray;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #a3d063;
  border: 2px solid #a3d063;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message:hover {
  color: #a3d063;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message .text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.message_template {
  display: none;
}


</style>

 <style type="text/css">

        .answerbot-input
        {
            color: #1AA1E1;
        }
        .answerbot-ai
        {
            color: #CE5043;
        }

    </style>

</head><body>




<div class="chat_window"><div class="top_menu"><div class="buttons"><div class="button close"></div><div class="button minimize"></div><div class="button maximize"></div></div><div class="title">Chat</div></div>
<div class="bottom_wrapper clearfix">

<div class="subcontent" id='subcontent'>
                    <p class='answerbot-ai'>
                        Don't be afraid, talk to me.
                    </p>
                </div>

<div class="message_input_wrapper">
<input class="message_input" placeholder="Type your message here..." onkeyup="keypressInput(this, event);"/>
</div><div class="send_message">
<div class="icon"></div><div class="text">Send</div></div></div></div>
</li></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _answerBot = new answerBot();
        function keypressInput(sender, event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                document.getElementById('subcontent').innerHTML += _answerBot.processInput(sender.value);
                sender.value = '';

            }
        }


    </script>


</body></html>
```

This is the scripts.js file:

```
var answerBot = function () {
    var _this = this;
    _this.processInput = function (text) {
        updateUrl(text);
        var _result = "<p class='answerbot-input'>" + text + "</p>";
        text = text.replace(new RegExp("[ ]{2,}", "g"), " ");
        var _words = text.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        var _answers = [];
        var _title = "";
        if (_words.length === 0 || _words.toString() === '') { //if the input is empty
            _answers = _this.specialContext.emptyInput;
            _title = _this.specialContext.emptyInput;
        } else {
            var _possibleAnswers = findMatches(_words);
            if (_possibleAnswers.length === 0) { //if no answer found
                _answers = _this.specialContext.wrongInput;
                _title = _this.specialContext.wrongInput;
            }
            if (_possibleAnswers.length == 1) { //context recognized
                _answers = _this.answers[_possibleAnswers[0]].values;
                _title = _this.answers[_possibleAnswers[0]].description;
            }
            if (_possibleAnswers.length > 1) {
                _result += formatText(_this.specialContext.rephrase, _this.specialContext.rephrase);
                for (var i = 0; i < _possibleAnswers.length; i++) {
                    _result += formatText(_this.answers[_possibleAnswers[i]].description, _this.answers[_possibleAnswers[i]].description);
                }
            }
        }
        if (_answers.length > 0) {
            var _rand = Math.floor((Math.random() - 0.001) * _answers.length);
            _result += formatText(_answers[_rand], _title);
        }
        return _result;
    };

    function formatText(text, title) {
        return "<p class=\'answerbot-ai\' title=\'" + title + "\'>" + text + "</p>";
    }

    function findMatches(words) {
        var foundKeywords = [];
        var _possibleAnswers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < _this.keywords.length; i++) {
            foundKeywords[i] = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if (_this.keywords[i].keys.indexOf(words[j]) >= 0) {
                    foundKeywords[i]++;
                    if (foundKeywords[i] == _this.keywords[i].keys.length) {
                        return [_this.keywords[i].value];
                    }
                }
            }
            if (foundKeywords[i] * 2 > _this.keywords[i].keys.length) {
                _possibleAnswers.push(_this.keywords[i].value);
            }
        }
        return _possibleAnswers.filter(function (elem, pos) {
            return _possibleAnswers.indexOf(elem) == pos;
        });
    }

    function updateUrl(text){
        history.pushState(null, null, "#question=" + encodeURIComponent(text));
        if(typeof ga === "function")//google analytics
            ga('send', 'event', 'question', text);
    }
};
```

And this is the data.js file:

```
if (answerBot) {
    answerBot.prototype.specialContext = {
        "wrongInput": ["I don't understand you.", "Could you rephrase the question?"],
        "emptyInput": ["Please say something", "Speak louder", "Well i can't read minds."],
        "rephrase": ["Can you tell me if your question was about one of the following things:"]
    };

    answerBot.prototype.keywords = [
        { "keys": ["hi"], "value": 0 },
        { "keys": ["hello"], "value": 0 },
        { "keys": ["life", "universe", "everything"], "value": 1 },
        { "keys": ["software", "development"], "value": 2 },
        { "keys": ["software", "engineering"], "value": 2 },
        { "keys": ["who", "made", "you"], "value": 3 },
        { "keys": ["who", "wrote", "you"], "value": 3 },
        { "keys": ["who", "coded", "you"], "value": 3 },
        { "keys": ["is", "this", "real", "life"], "value": 4 },
        { "keys": ["who", "is", "deni"], "value": 5 },
        { "keys": ["tell", "me", "about", "deni"], "value": 5 },
        { "keys": ["tell", "me", "about", "author"], "value": 5 },
        { "keys": ["show", "me", "author"], "value": 5 },
        { "keys": ["can", "see", "source"], "value": 6 },
        { "keys": ["can", "see", "sourcecode"], "value": 6 },
        { "keys": ["show", "me", "code"], "value": 6 },
        { "keys": ["how", "are", "you"], "value": 7 },
        { "keys": ["who", "is", "this"], "value": 8 }];

    answerBot.prototype.answers = [
        {
            "description": "Hi!",
            "values": ["Hello there!", "Hi how can I help you today", "Hi! What brings you here?"]
        },
        {
            "description": "What is the answer to life the universe and everything?",
            "values": ["42"]
        },
        {
            "description": "What is software development?",
            "values": ["Programming! Do you speak it?"]
        },
        {
            "description": "Who created me?",
            "values": ["I was created by another <a href='http://about.me/deni' target='_blank'>bot</a>.", "The question is who sent you here?"]
        },
        {
            "description": "Is this real life?",
            "values": ["No this is the internetz!", "Find out <a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txqiwrbYGrs' target='_blank'>yourself</a>!"]
        },
        {
            "description": "Who is Deni?",
            "values": ["This is his <a href='https://plus.google.com/+DeniSpasovski/' target='_blank'>G+ profile</a>.", "This is his <a href='www.linkedin.com/in/denispasovski' target='_blank'>Linkedin profile</a>."]
        },
        {
            "description": "Where is your source?",
            "values": ["Here is the <a href='https://github.com/denimf/Answer-bot' target='_blank'>source</a>."]
        },
        {
            "description": "How are you?",
            "values": ["I'm good how are you?"]
        },
        {
            "description": "Who is this?",
            "values": ["StackOverflow Exception occurred", "The question is who are you?"]
        }
        ];
}
```

As you can see, the chat works very well answering questions and I'm looking forward to implementing it with the questions I want to be answered. However, I'm having some issues that, despite how much I try, I can't seem to fix! (I don't know that much about coding, I apologize in advance!)

1. I can't fix the title on top. If you write enough, it will end up disappearing because new messages push it out of the chat window.
2. I can't seem to allow scrolling to see past messages... I've tried with overflow scroll and it doesn't work... The messages are fixed and I can't move up the timeline
3. I can't get the Send button to work either! The chat only works with the Enter key.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: u need to attach an onclick event to the send button (pretty much similar to the keypress event you already have. Right now there's nothing happening when you click on send so it's no surprise its not working for you. Try reading a few javascript tutorials, it will all look clearer .

Comment: u have several places with overflow: hidden in your css, remove all of them. see if any of them fixes it

Comment: @Joel_Blum Nope. That doesn't work :(

Comment: I also can't get to work your onclick advice